# How to unzip file in Python on all OSes?

Tags: python, zip

Is there a simple Python function that would allow unzipping a .zip file like so?:

```
unzip(ZipSource, DestinationDirectory)
```

I need the solution to act the same on Windows, Mac and Linux: always produce a file if the zip is a file, directory if the zip is a directory, and directory if the zip is multiple files; always inside, not at, the given destination directory

How do I unzip a file in Python?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module in the standard library:

```
import zipfile,os.path
def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
        for member in zf.infolist():
            # Path traversal defense copied from
            # http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/http/server.py#l789
            words = member.filename.split('/')
            path = dest_dir
            for word in words[:-1]:
                while True:
                    drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
                    head, word = os.path.split(word)
                    if not drive:
                        break
                if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir, ''):
                    continue
                path = os.path.join(path, word)
            zf.extract(member, path)
```

Note that using [`extractall`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) would be a lot shorter, but that method does **not** protect against [path traversal vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_traversal) before Python 2.7.4. If you can guarantee that your code runs on recent versions of Python.

Comment: Would a vulnerable zip file have to be created specifically for an attack, or is it just a result of bad practice?

Comment: @tkbx: Both are possible. E.g. with absolute pathnames.

Comment: In that case, what would be the alternative to extractall() that doesn't have this issue? Does the issue happen when the zip is made with pwd as /?

Comment: @tkbx Updated with a safe alternative.

Comment: Seems strange that this hasn't been made into something like unzip(), or even zipfile.unzip() would be better. Thanks anyway, though, this is much better than os.system('unzip...') and no Windows support.

Comment: @phihag This is giving me an error: `with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_src) as zf: AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__'` (my `zip_src` is `source_filename`

Comment: @tkbx That means you're using an outdated Python version. Either update to 3.3 (or 2.7), or replace `with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:` with `zf = zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename)` and unindent the rest of it. That will leak the zipfile on some Python implementations though.

Comment: @phihag I used the implementation that you posted and it has an odd behavior (python3.3 OSX). It extract the files into the correct directory. Say file z.zip contains a single file a/b/c.txt, this implementation unzips that file into a/b/a/b/c.txt. I was able to fix this by doing `if(member.filename.split('/').pop()): member.filename = member.filename.split('/').pop() zf.extract(member, path)` right after checking the paths.

Comment: Note that starting from Python 2.7.4 the path traversal vulnerability [has been fixed](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract).

Comment: Thanks, I used this snippet of code here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1928/1511

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.x use -e argument, not -h.. such as:

```
python -m zipfile -e compressedfile.zip c:\output_folder
```

arguments are as follows..

```
zipfile.py -l zipfile.zip        # Show listing of a zipfile
zipfile.py -t zipfile.zip        # Test if a zipfile is valid
zipfile.py -e zipfile.zip target # Extract zipfile into target dir
zipfile.py -c zipfile.zip src ... # Create zipfile from sources
```