# Unable to unzip using python zipfile module

Tags: python, python-zipfile

```
def unzip(zipPath, dstPath):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, "r") as z:
        z.extractall(dstPath)
```

I'm using the above code to unzip an Archive. When I'm using '7-zip' tool to unzip, it pauses at one stage and asks `"Destination folder already contains processed file. Would you like to replace it with existing file ?"` 
On the GUI, I give "Yes to All"

Due to this I'm getting `WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:` exception.

But how to solve the above problem ?

I'm using python in Windows machine.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886768/how-to-unzip-file-in-python-on-all-oses ?

Comment: Thanks, Its a way implemented to extract member after a member.. But it is not helping...

Comment: So it works using 7-zip w/ gui but not using zipfile?

Comment: Yes, right. And '7-zip' asks for replacing the file. May be I need to find a way to tell 'zipfile' to replace the files. (Not sure)

Comment: Surely it asks to replace files because you already have them at that location?

Comment: Have you tried finding out what file is causing this error by extracting one file at a time?

Comment: Ya, Let me try that.. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103815/discussion-between-shree-harsha-s-and-m-t).